How can you use awk to replace a pattern with an environment variable?
I am trying to write a simple script that will receive a text via standard input and will output everything as it is except it will replace occurences following this pattern:
{{env MYVAR}} 
{{env PATH}} 
{{env DISPLAY}} 

with the contents of environment variable MYVAR, PATH, DISPLAY, etc.
I am aiming to not having to pass any parameter to this script, so it will automatically detect the patterns {{env VARNAME}} and replace by the value of environment variable $VARNAME.
The script takes its input via standard input and provides the output via standard output.
Sample input text via standard input:
This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is {{env DISPLAY}} and the path is {{env PATH}}.

Expected output via standard output:
This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is :0.0 and the path is /bin;/usr/bin;/usr/local/bin.

What I have tried:
So far I have managed only to get it done for one variable by passing it via command line.
#!/bin/sh

# Check if the first argument is set
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "No variable name provided." >&2
    exit 1
fi

VARIABLE_NAME="$1"

# Use awk to replace '{{env VARIABLE_NAME}}' with the value of the environment variable
awk -v var_name="$VARIABLE_NAME" '
function escape(s) {
    esc = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= length(s); i++) {
        c = substr(s, i, 1);
        if (c ~ /[.[\]$()*+?^{|\\{}]/) {
            esc = esc "\\" c;
        } else {
            esc = esc c;
        }
    }
    return esc;
}
BEGIN {
    search = "{{env " var_name "}}";
    search_esc = escape(search);
    replacement = ENVIRON[var_name];
}
{
    gsub(search_esc, replacement);
    print;
}'

So the above works but requires you to do ./parsing_script MYVAR
I want to avoid having to specify the environment variables as command line arguments.
Architecture/OS
I am using FreeBSD's awk and its POSIX shell /bin/sh
Notes
If awk is not the tool, I am open to hear solutions (please no Python or Perl).

please update the question with a couple more examples of environment variables (in the same file) making sure to provide at least one example where you expect the escape() function to be needed

there is no mention of the input file in your script so it would be of interest to see how you're calling the script as well as what you're doing with the output (dumping to stdout? saving to another file? updating the current file?); please update the question with an example of how you're calling your script to include the sample variable name and input file; you state this script works for a single env variable ... can you just call the script multiple times, once for each env variable?

#markp-fuso no files, stdin/stdout

You say you are using "its POSIX shell /bin/sh" but you tagged this with bash but bash is not native to or automatically installed on FreeBSD.

@Rob that is indeed true and certainly it might be not properly tagged, but normally the bash community is friendly and open to POSIX shell questions and it is the best place to ask due to the extensive shell programming knowledge you find there. There is no active POSIX shell community/tag as far as I know. Additionally, since bash supports POSIX shell, could that be considered a question on a subset of the language?

The following should work with any POSIX awk. Note that it performs the substitution recursively. If environment variable A={{env B}} and  environment variable B=bar, then {{env A}} will be replaced with bar.
It use regular expression [{][{]env[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*[}][}] because a valid shell variable name is A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore. So, it will not substitute {{env 98FOO}}.
The space between {{env and the variable name can be any mixture of tabs and whitespaces.
#!/bin/sh

cat - | awk '
BEGIN { re = "[{][{]env[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*[}][}]" }
$0 ~ re {
  s = $0
  while(match(s, re)) {
    v = substr(s, RSTART + 6, RLENGTH - 8)
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "", v)
    s = substr(s, 1, RSTART - 1) ENVIRON[v] substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  }
  print s
  next
}
1'

As mentioned in comments the recursive substitution could lead to infinite loops (e.g. with A='{{env A}}'). A version with only one pass of substitutions could be something like:
BEGIN { re = "[{][{]env[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*[}][}]" }
$0 ~ re {
  s = $0
  while(match(s, re)) {
    v = substr(s, RSTART + 6, RLENGTH - 8)
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, "", v)
    printf("%s%s", substr(s, 1, RSTART - 1), ENVIRON[v])
    s = substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  }
  print s
  next
}
1' input

But of course, with A='{{env B}}' and B=bar, {{env A}} will become {{env B}}, not bar.

Thanks Renaud. But I am aiming to not having to pass any parameter to this script, so it will automatically detect the patterns {{env VARNAME}} and replace by the value of enviroment variable $VARNAME

Oh, I see. May I suggest that you edit your question to make this clear?

Added the remark.

Thanks a lot Renaud, I was about to drop the towel and code it in C.

Careful: I just fixed a small error. The regex shall be {{env[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*}}, not {{env[[:space:]]+[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+}}, else single letter variables are not properly processed.

Couldn't that spiral off into an infinite loop if MYVAR was defined as MYVAR='{{env MYVAR}}' or similar? You normally want to not revisit the replaced text with these sort of problems, start the next loop iteration from substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH instead of substr(str,1

@markp-fuso With bash, try export A='{{env B}}' B=bar; awk '...' <<< '{{env A}}'.

@EdMorton Thanks for the curly braces, I fixed the regex. And yes, there could be an infinite loop. We could even create one with a cycle involving several variables. But as the OP does not explain if they prefer a recursive or one pass substitution I picked the recursive one. Restarting from the tail instead of the beginning would indeed implement the one pass version. I add this.

Assumptions:

there is exactly one space between the string env and the variable name
for undefined variables we will leave the {{env UNDEFINED_VARIABLE}} string in place

Sample input file:
$ cat sample.dat
This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is {{env DISPLAY}} and the custom var MYVAR={{env MYVAR}}.
Handling missing variable DOESNOTEXIST={{env DOESNOTEXIST}} and empty var EMPTY_VAR={{env EMPTY_VAR}}.

One awk idea that verifies the environment variable exists before attempting a replacement:
$ cat parsing_script
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=":0.2"
export MYVAR="something_like_this"
export EMPTY_VAR=""

awk '
{ line = $0
  out  = ""
  while (match(line,/{{env [^}]+}}/)) {
        var = substr(line,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6-2)
        if (var in ENVIRON)                                 # is this a valid variable?
           out = out substr(line,1,RSTART-1) ENVIRON[var]
        else
           out = out substr(line,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
        line = substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  print out line
}
' "${@:--}"                                                 # allow for reading from explicit file or stdin

Taking for a test drive:
########
# read from stdin

cat sample.dat | ./parsing_script

########
# read from explicit file reference

./parsing_script sample.dat

These both generate:
This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is :0.2 and the custom var MYVAR=something_like_this.
Handling missing variable DOESNOTEXIST={{env DOESNOTEXIST}} and empty var EMPTY_VAR=.


You may use this awk solution:
awk 'NF {
   s = ""
   while (match($0, /\{\{env [_[:alnum:]]+}}/)) {
      s = s substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) ENVIRON[substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-8)]
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
   $0 = s $0
}
1' file

This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is :0.0 and the path is /bin;/usr/bin;/usr/local/bin.

If you are using gnu awk then you can simplify it further by using a capture group parameter in the match function:
awk 'NF {
   s = ""
   while (match($0, /\{\{env[[:blank:]]+([_[:alnum:]]+)}}/, m)) {
      s = s substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) ENVIRON[m[1]]
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
   $0 = s $0
}
1' file


Thanks @EdMorton I have modified my answer to address both the issues.

export PATH='/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin'
export DISPLAY=':0.0'
cat file | sed 's/{{env \([^ ]\+\)}}/${\1}/g' | envsubst

Output:

This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is :0.0 and the path is /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin.

See: man envsubst

Thanks for sharing, envsubst is simple and can be a good tool indeed. However if I understood the man page correctly this solution will replace every $MYVAR occurence, not every {{env MYVAR}}. The idea is to have a basic templating that can not collide with regular source code. But I am happy to know about it as it can be very useful.

Using GNU awk for the 3rg arg to match(), \w shorthand for [[:alnum:]_], and { being literal at the start of a regexp or when not followed by a digit:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        head = ""
        tail = $0
        while ( match(tail, /({{env (\w+)}})(.*)/, a) ) {
            var  = a[2]
            head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) (var in ENVIRON ? ENVIRON[var] : a[1])
            tail = a[3]
        }
        print head tail
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ export DISPLAYX=':0.0'
$ export PATHX='/bin;/usr/bin;/usr/local/bin'


$ ./tst.sh file
This is a basic templating system that can replace environment variables in regular text files.
For example the DISPLAY in this system is :0.0 and the path is /bin;/usr/bin;/usr/local/bin.

I'm crawling along tail populating head rather than constantly re-constructing and re-evaluating $0 to avoid re-evaluating a previously replaced string so something like DISPLAY='{{env DISPLAY}}' doesn't cause an infinite loop.
If you want variables to be able to expand to {{env OTHER_VAR}} and then also expand THAT, then change the above to:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        delete seen
        while ( !seen[$0]++ ) {
            head = ""
            tail = $0
            while ( match(tail, /({{env (\w+)}})(.*)/, a) ) {
                var  = a[2]
                head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) (var in ENVIRON ? ENVIRON[var] : a[1])
                tail = a[3]
            }
            $0 = head tail
        }
        print
    }
' "${@:--}"

to stop expanding variables when you see a $0 that has already been processed and thereby avoid an infinite loop.
I put an X at the end of the variable names in the sample shell code and sample input as I didn't want to mess up my real DISPLAY and PATH.
If you use {{env FOO}} and FOO isn't an environment variable then that text won't be changed.
